# Facebook Graph api me/posts and me/feed not getting receiving any wall posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using me/posts and me/feed I am not able to get any wall posts at all(i.e something posted on my wall by others or vice versa). I've tried various accounts with the same results. Is this due to some changes on Facebook? Do you guys experience it too and what can be the problem?

Even using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed&version=v2.2&) it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a permission problem, you need the read_stream permission in order to get the news feed of a user. Look into the tools that Facebook provides, like the Graph API tool and the token debugger. Between those two you should be able to detect the problem.

Comment: I am using the Graph API Explorer and have all the permissions and an access token. Does it work for you? See the edited question